# pylint wingIDE not working

Tags: pylint, wing-ide

I'm trying for the first time wingIDE. I setup wingIDE environment to utilize the `/urs/local/bin/python3`. I install pylint with the following command... `pip3 install pylint`. I test pylint utilizing the terminal and is working. However, following wingIDE instructions to fire pylint, I have no errors showing in the IDE. Does anyone knows if wingIDE has a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Messages tool's Scripts channel for messages from the pylint integration.  The most common thing is you need to right-click on the Pylint tool in Wing and select Configure and then set 'command' to the full path of the pylint you want to use.  If this doesn't help please email the error-log (or in Wing 6+ ide.log) file from your settings directory, which is listed 5th in Wing's About box, to support@wingware.com.

Comment: It is a way to setup pylint to run on saving the file?

Comment: Not currently, although it would be possible to modify scripts/pylintpanel.py in your Wing installation to do it by connecting to the save-point signal on all documents.  I'll also add this as a feature request.